# Create a function based on a table of values.

Tags: functions

Alright, so I have [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0AAI.png) of data.

I want to find the function to calculate the remaining fields marked with a "?" using the constant on the left.

I am assuming (just by looking at these values in a graph) that the function I need is an exponential function.

Now my question is, how would I approach finding the right function for this?
I've tried several things the past few days but I just can't get my head around it.

I don't want the full solution, but I'd love to get some kind of kickstart in the right direction.

Comment: Functions in 2 variables can be bothersome to compute/guess unless you have some background on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For such kind of problems you may make some experiments using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).
A 'bestfit' for the first line is [not very satisfying](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bestfit%20111,%20142,%20200,%20342,1070) but considering the reciprocals gives you [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bestfit%201%2F111,1%2F142,1%2F200,1%2F342,1%2F1070).
Even a linear interpolation seems good enough and suggests that $f(1,70)$ could be near $\,90$ !

The first and second line are nearly generated by 
\begin{align}
f(x,70)&\approx\dfrac 1{0.0131215 - 0.00203371 \,x}\\
f(x,100)&\approx\dfrac 1{0.00879286 - 0.00140815 \,x}\\
\end{align}

Your next problem is to find a fit between the values $70, 100$ and the coefficients at the right. Observe that $\,\dfrac{0.00203371}{0.00140815}$ is not too far from $\,\dfrac{100}{70}\,$ and that the ratio of coefficients in the two denominators are near.

We may thus propose the (very) rough approximation :
$$f(x,y)\approx \frac y{0.9-0.141\,x}$$

To get something more precise we may minimize the sum of the squares of the differences between $f_{rat}(x,y)=\dfrac{ay}{1-bx-cy}\;$ and the values in your table (I used [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) for that purpose, many other [optimization algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) exist). I obtained :
$$f_{rat}(x,y)\approx \frac{1.08386\;y}{1- 0.1449\,x -0.0008513\,y}$$
These approximations will become singular for $x$ a little larger than $6$.
Let's try your exponential suggestion with $\exp(a+b\,x+c\,y)$ but the resulting :
$$f_{exp}(x,y)\approx \exp(-1.59+1.129\,x+0.02575\,y)$$
is increasing too fast so let's combine rational and exponential to get :
$$f_{mix}(x,y)\approx \frac{\exp(3.2177+0.0248\,x+0.01397\,y)}{1-0.145777\,x-0.0007615\,y}$$

\begin{array} {c|cccc|cccc}
x&f(x,70)&f_{rat}(x,70)&f_{exp}(x,70)&f_{mix}(x,70)&f(x,100)&f_{rat}(x,100)&f_{exp}(x,100)&f_{mix}(x,100)\\
\hline
1&?&95.37&3.8&85.0&135&140.8&8.3&133.0\\
2&111&116.6&11.8&106.5&167&173.4&25.6&167.8\\
3&142&150.0&36.6&140.4&219&225.7&79.2&223.5\\
4&200&210.3&113.3&201.6&321&212.3&244.9&327,2\\
5&342&351.4&349.8&345.0&592&569.3&757.5&586.2\\
6&1070&1068.5&1081.9&1069.6&2382&2383.7&2342.6&2381.8\\
\end{array}

Extrapolating a third line from only two lines doesn't make much sense without knowledge of the process involved. Anyway for the fun here are the results with the three functions :

\begin{array} {c|ccc}
x&f_{rat}(x,170)&f_{exp}(x,170)&f_{mix}(x,170)\\
\hline
1&259.4&50.2&379.7\\
2&325.8&155.3&487.2\\
3&438.1&480.3&667.5\\
4&668.4&1485.5&1031.3\\
5&1408.9&4594.0&2145.1\\
6&-13048&14207&-75662\\
\end{array}